# jpeg image for pyqt 5 not loaded when .exe is created using cx_freeze

Tags: python, jpeg, pyqt5, cx-freeze

I have searched through all the existing solutions for this problem and tried all of them but I am not able to load my images in Pyqt5 through my executable. Solutions tried are as follows:
1. copied image formats folder into appdir and the dlls into the appdir itself
2. copied plugins folder into appdir

Here is my code snippet:

```
def __init__(self):

    QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    Ui_abt_sw.__init__(self)
    #self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
    self.setupUi(self)
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # frozen
        scriptDir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
        # unfrozen
        scriptDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(scriptDir + os.path.sep + "dbIO_1.jpg" ))
    self.label_3.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(scriptDir + os.path.sep + 
                                                     "dbio_icon.jpg"))
```

I also tried adding the plugin folder files to the app as one of the solutions recommended.

if **name** == "**main**":

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # frozen
        scriptDir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
else:
        # unfrozen
        scriptDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

QtCore.QCoreApplication.addLibraryPath(scriptDir + os.path.sep + "plugins")   
QtGui.QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()
```

I have the jpeg files "dbio.jpg" and "dbIO_1.jpg" in my appdir. After trying everything I am unable to get the image(label) or the icon in the GUI if I run my .exe file created using cx_freeze. However if I run it from spyder (i use spyder on anaconda), the image is visible. The same issue applies to my window icons as well when I try adding them.

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.